# Mongodb Sharding not working - what is causing Collection not sharded

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, sharding

I am trying to set up mongodb sharding with two nodes. I have enabled 3 configuration process and a router process. I am extracting data (With 50 columns - 650 MB - _id as the key) from SQL server and putting in mongodb. In the pentaho configuration I have enabled "**Use all Replica sets"** and enter the primary node's host name and the port. When I run the transformation, all the data are getting into primary node and the other node is not getting data. When I entered, `db.table.getShardDistribution()`, I get the following message "**Collection not sharded**".

Also the status of `is.BalancerRunning()` gives me `false` status. I am very sure that background process balancer is not working here.

Mean while i tried to insert a sample test records 10,00,000 records with name as the key , the sharding setup was working fine and each shard got data distributed.

So,I am missing something or doing something wrong while I run pentaho transformation to populate data in mongodb. Any help is appreciated.

My set up

---

````
C:\Mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --shardsvr  --port 10001  --dbpath  C:\Mongodb\shard1      > C:\Mongodb\Log\shard1.log
C:\Mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --shardsvr  --port 10002  --dbpath  C:\Mongodb\shard2      > C:\Mongodb\Log\shard2.log
C:\Mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --configsvr --port 20000  --dbpath  C:\Mongodb\configdb    > C:\Mongodb\Log\config.log
C:\Mongodb\bin\mongos.exe --configdb 10.231.34.105:
 --chunkSize 1               > C:\Mongodb\Log\mongos.log


mongos> use admin
switched to dbadmin

mongos> db.runCommand( { addshard : "10.231.34.105:40001" } );
{ "shardAdded" : "shard0000", "ok" : 1 }

mongos> db.runCommand( { addshard : "10.231.34.106:40002" } );
{ "shardAdded" : "shard0001", "ok" : 1 }

mongos> db.runCommand( { enablesharding  : "dbTest" } );
{ "ok" : 1 }

mongos> db.runCommand( { shardcollection : "dbTest.cTest", key : { Date_ID: 1 } } );
{ "collectionssharded" : "dbTest.cTest", "ok" : 1 }

mongos> use dbTest;

db.cTest.ensureIndex({ Date_D : 1 });```
````

Comment: Can you connect a mongo shell to your mongos (router) instance, run sh.status() and provide the output here? sh.status() will provide a summary of your sharded setup.

Comment: sharding version: {
        "_id" : 1,
        "version" : 3,
        "minCompatibleVersion" : 3,
        "currentVersion" : 4,
        "clusterId" : ObjectId("532c4541d0b378244488e8fa")
}
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "10.231.34.105:40001" }
        {  "_id" : "shard0001",  "host" : "10.231.34.106:40002" }
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
        {  "_id" : "dbTest",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
        {  "_id" : "dTest",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "shard0001" }

Comment: I don't see any sharded collections in this output, assuming this is the full sh.status() output. One thing to try is to create the index on cTest before attempting to shard the collection. This may be a requirement depending on the version of MongoDB you are running.

Comment: but from the shard1, if I populate the table using the following code ::myData = "";while ( myData.length < 200000 )myData += "My data for mongodb sharding";for ( var num = 0; num < 5000; num++ ){db.cTest.save( { myData : myData } );}::: The data is splitting and moving to second shard as well. Initially I populated through external pentaho tool.In that tool I have configured the host names,port number (10001 ) . I am just confused about this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure from your post if you shard database and collections.

Once you setup shards did you enable sharding for database. like below

```
db.runCommand({
    enablesharding : "dbname"
});
```

Do `db.stats()` to confirm.

After enable sharding for collections. like below.

```
db.runCommand({
        shardcollection : "collection_name",
        key : {
            shardKey : "hashed"
        }
    });
```

Then to confirm `db.collections.stats()`

Comment: I entered both the commands. This is the result of db.collection.stats()

        "sharded" : false,
        "primary" : "shard0000",
        "ns" : "dbTest.cTest",
        "count" : 128000,
        "size" : 95225584,
        "avgObjSize" : 743.949875,
        "storageSize" : 131043328,
        "numExtents" : 11,
        "nindexes" : 1,
        "lastExtentSize" : 38096896,
        "paddingFactor" : 1,
        "systemFlags" : 1,
        "userFlags" : 0,
        "totalIndexSize" : 4161584,
        "indexSizes" : {
                "_id_" : 4161584
        },
        "ok" : 1
}

Comment: I could see the Sharded Option gives me false as the result.. In the question,I have edited and added my setup configuration

Comment: Choose the shard key properly